# How to select all checkboxes in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular7

I have already selected all checkbox.

```
selectAllCheckbox(): void {
  for (const task of this.tasks) {
  task.done = true;
 }
}
```

Now I need to check it and dis select all checkbox.

Comment: why can't you loop over them again and deselect just like you select them here?

Comment: please elobrate more, that'll help us to give accurate answer